# Prerelease build upload to ITunes Connect using altool does not send email invites to internal testers

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, application-loader

I'm trying to integrate the build upload step to our CI process. For this I am using the Application Loader command line utility "altool".

I have existing pre-release builds and internal testers already set up in ITunes Connect.

When I upload a new build **using Application Loader** I see the following
in ITunes Connect, as expected:

> - build is uploaded and can be seen under Prerelease/Builds
> - Invitation emails are sent to internal testers almost immediately
> - "Active (30 Days Left)" under Internal in Prerelease/Builds

When I upload a new build using  **altool** (below command),

```
altool --upload-app -f FileName.ipa -u 'username' -p 'password'
```

I see the following in ITunes Connect:

> - build is uploaded and can be seen under Prerelease/Builds
> - Invitation emails are **not** sent to internal testers
> - "Invite Testers" under Internal in Prerelease/Builds

I would expect the invites to be sent out as soon as I upload a build.

Am I missing any additional step/parameter to trigger these invites with altool? Does anyone else have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invites were sent after around 12 hours of the App submission. It seems email servers were slow.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK for every new **version** you have to enable TestFlight beta testing, for that new version of the app, on iTunes Connect. You don't have to do this if only the **build number** changes.

You can automate this process (enabling the new version for testing) with [deliver](https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver) for example. Deliver uploads the new build, waits until it's processed and enables it for TestFlight beta testing after that (if you use the `--beta` flag for the command as you can see it here: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-deploy-to-itunesconnect-deliver/blob/master/step.sh ).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I have already created the ipa using command line. All I am trying is to upload this ipa to ITunes Connect using the altool command.

Comment: @coder_andy deliver does exactly that, you can provide an IPA for it as an input as you can see it in the second link. It's not well documented on deliver's page, but it's certainly possible.